# No Navigation bar iOS7+ app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, hidden

What is the best way to build an app without navigation bar ?
I'm going to work on an app from scratch which includes about few navigation but there is no navigation bar. Definitely there will be navigation controller.

I know we can hide navigation bar by setting hidden property as YES. Is there any best recommended approach to build such kind of app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your plist and do the below

[image]

one more thing on add the below line

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [_navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Not working... ViewController is still showing navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Just be careful not to place the view contents below the status bar (that is if you don't hide the status bar) and to place a back button somewhere to manually pop view controllers.